# AEM: Non-US IP visitors

Tags: redirect, adobe, aem

How can I add a filter for `Non-US IP` visitors? To redirect on specific page.

I hear that i could be to leverage the redirect logic used within Adobe Target. But i can not find  information about it.

Someone know about it?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is a targeted component within AEM that has a client side redirect implemented. The side effect would be a flicker of the page that is starting to load before the redirect happens. Doing something similar on the server could probably also be achieved, though you would take caching on the dispatcher into account.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom [Sling filter](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html) that handles IP detection and checks if the requests is for a specific page. Like Thomas said, you must take dispatcher caching into account.